# Run Android app inside a Windows Phone project

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I would like to know if it's possible to run code from an Android app in a Universal Windows Phone app.

As far as I know, you can compile and execute a solution which has code in C# and in VB at the same time (I'm aware that this case wouldn't be the same as both C# and VB belong to the same framework) so, would it be possible to do the same but using Java?

I have been looking into Xamarin.Forms, but I guess that's not what I need as I want to recycle a code already written, not to build a project using a cross-platform.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not just for this question. Many times I've seen and asked questions about programming issues and people have vote negatively. And not just that... look into what stackoverflow explains it is in its help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. I think asking about a SDK to run Android apps in a UWP project is a question about software developers commonly use.

Comment: The comment was not addressed to you, sorry. I wanted to thank you for replying anyway. But it really annoys me because sometimes you come across issues or questions that drive one mad, you don't find any pleasant answer to your own question investigating and when you ask for help in an experts forum, people vote your question negatively. I'm not in favour to ask  something at the slightest, but neither to not allow people to ask something even if the most think it's a stupidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 10 Microsoft will be introducing "Universal Windows Platform Bridges" which will allow Android Developers to port there existing Code to a Windows App for Windows 10 Mobile. The SDK is not available yet but this is probably what you're looking for.

> " ”Project Astoria” will enable you to build apps using Android code
>   to target Windows 10 phones without having to leave your Android IDE"

Find Details here:
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/uwp-bridges/

Also check this:
http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/22/getting-ready-for-windows-10-sdks-compatibility-bridges/

Comment: Thank you very much!! That's what I was looking for precisly! :)